# LibGDX/Hiero - font generator issue

Tags: fonts, libgdx

Maybe some of the LibGDX developers will help me here. When I generate a font with Hiero with parameters visible below:

[Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdRn6.png)

I get a font which makes a strange result:
[Strange text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Vcj.png)

As you can see, there is a space after the 'U' letter and after 'N' letter, and there is no gap after 'A', probably caused by 'N'.

I don't know what's wrong with this, I made everything accordingly to LibGDX tutorial ***github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero***.

Images are in links, cause I don't have enough reputation to post them! :)

If someone could help me, I would be grateful :)

Comment: If you aren't using a ScreenViewport, call font.setUseIntegerPositions(false);

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, text is still the same (i checked, the boolean value was true, so it has changed) but with no result.